# Maven isn't looking for dependencies in all provided repositories

Tags: java, maven

I have settings.xml with custom repositories for maven:

```
     <repositories>
                    <repository>
                        <id>id1</id>
                        <name>name1</name>
                        <releases>
                            <enabled>false</enabled>
                        </releases>
                        <snapshots>
                            <enabled>true</enabled>
                            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                        </snapshots>
                        <url>url1</url>
                        <layout>default</layout>
                    </repository>
                    <repository>
                        <id>id2</id>
                        <name>name2</name>
                        <snapshots>
                            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                        </snapshots>
                        <releases>
                            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                        </releases>
                        <url>url2</url>
                    </repository>
                    <repository>
                        <id>id3</id>
                        <url>url3</url>
                        <snapshots>
                            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                        </snapshots>
                        <releases>
                            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                        </releases>
                    </repository>
                    <repository>
                    
                        <id>id4</id>
                        <url>url4</url>
                        <snapshots>
                            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                        </snapshots>
                        <releases>
                            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                        </releases>
                    </repository>
<repositories>
```

The dependency is present in url4 repository, however when i try to `mvn clean install` the project it stops at 2nd url and says it cannot find it here. Why is this happening? Why is it stopping there?

Comment: Do you have any `<mirror>` entries in your `settings.xml`?

Comment: Your closing `<repositories>` should be `</repositories>`

Answer (score -1):

Settings xml file contains the details for possible servers to fetch from , you still need to specify them in the projects pom.xml (by specifying at least id) the separation between settings.xml and pom.xml is done so that pom.xml will not contain any sensitive data as it is usually committed.

As for why it stops at the 2nd url im not sure it is necessarily looks by a specific order .

Another point to consider is if for some reason you have tried to resolve the dependency and it was not in the repository at that time you will have to manually delete the caching file of that dependency from your .m2 repo under your os user directory